# Iteration and memory problems in Django

Tags: python, django

I need to create pairs of hashtags so people can judge whether the two tags in question refer to the same thing. The problem is that there are A LOT of hashtags, and I'm running the code on a Dreamhost VPS, so my memory is somewhat limited.

Here's my relevant models:

```
class Hashtag(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    competitors = models.ManyToManyField('Hashtag', through='Competitors')
    tweet = models.ManyToManyField('Tweet')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode_escape(self.text)

class Competitors(models.Model):
    tag1 = models.ForeignKey('Hashtag', related_name='+')
    tag2 = models.ForeignKey('Hashtag', related_name='+')
    yes = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, null=False)
    no = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, null=False)
    objects = models.Manager()

def __unicode__(self):
    return u'{0} vs {1}'.format(unicode_escape(self.tag1.text), unicode_escape(self.tag2.text))
```

Here's the code I've developed to create the Competitors objects and save them to my DB:

```
class Twitterator(object):
    def __init__(self, infile=None, outfile=None, verbosity=True):
    ...
        self.competitors_i = 1
    ...

    def __save_comps__(self,tag1, tag2):
        try:
            comps = Competitors(id=self.competitors_i,
                                tag1=tag1,
                                tag2=tag2,
                                yes=0,
                                no=0)
            comps.save()
        except IntegrityError:
            self.competitors_i += 1
            self.save_comps(tag1, tag2)
        else:
            self.competitors_i += 1

    def competitors_to_db(self, start=1):
        tags = Hashtag.objects.all()
        i = start
        while True:
            try:
                tag1 = tags.get(pk=i)
                j = i + 1
                while True:
                    try:
                        tag2 = tags.get(pk=j)
                        self.__save_comps__(tag1, tag2)
                        j += 1
                    except Hashtag.DoesNotExist:
                        break
                i += 1
            except Hashtag.DoesNotExist:
                break
```

It all "works", but never manages to get that far before I run out of memory and the whole thing gets killed. I thought using .get would be less memory-intensive, but it doesn't seem to be less memory-intensive enough. I'm under the impression that Django Querysets are iterators already, so my usual 'make an iterator' trick is out. Any suggestions for further reducing my memory footprint?

Comment: Well what DB are you using?

Comment: Why do you even care to save all combination of Hashtags? (This is data duplication, because this is a derivative of the information already stored.) Wouldn't it suffice to only create rows in case you have a 'yes'?

Comment: @danodonovan: I'm using MySQL 5.1. @gertvdijk: I need both 'yes' and 'no' in order to differentiate between pairs that get 'no' votes and pairs that just haven't been seen. The final metric is going to be something like `# of yes votes / (# of total votes) >= some threshold`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in this function, `i` is not getting incremented properly and you will keep looping for same value of `i`.

```
def competitors_to_db(self, start=1):
        tags = Hashtag.objects.all()
        i = start
        while True:
            try:
                tag1 = tags.get(pk=i)
                j = i + 1
                while True:
                    try:
                        tag2 = tags.get(pk=j)
                        self.__save_comps__(tag1, tag2)
                        j += 1
                    except Hashtag.DoesNotExist:
                        break  #<------move this after i +=1 otherwise i will not increment 
                        i += 1
```

Comment: Sorry, that was my bad--I messed up the indentation. That `i += 1` is not actually under that `except` statement. (I fixed it up above).

Comment: @swizzard, The new place also does not seem correct. It should be out of 2nd `while` loop.

Comment: You're right--but the indentation's correct in my actual code (i.e., `i += 1` is indented only as much as the inner `while True` loop.) I'm just not very good at properly formatting my code on SO, I guess.